# How do i add button style cells to table views in iPhone apps?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uikit

I'm not able to find any specific examples in apple's documentation on this.  I want to add two to three buttons to a table view programmatically, much like the contacts app does with the send text message/ add to favorites buttons on a contacts's info.  does anyone know how to configure this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I've done in my apps is create a view with the buttons on it and return that view in the `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection`: and/or `tableView:viewForFooterInSection:` methods of the UITableView delegate.